# AWS SES - Changing AWS Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-ses

I'm working with a client right now that has a legacy application hosted by a 3rd party vendor on their amazon account.  That legacy app was using Amazon SES for their mailing.

I created the clients own amazon account (as I don't have access to continue the build out on clients account), and am now seeing the issue where I need to transition the SES DNS validation over to their account.

I'm wondering what kind of downtime I would see, or problems I'd create by updating the DNS entry of `_amazonses.mydomain.com` from what it was on the past account to this new account.

My concern is by updating that entry, I would break the legacy system which I don't have the ability to update.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any downtime, you can verify the domains in two different account, it just you need to add multiple TXT value to the record "_amazonses.mydomain.com".

e.g: _amazonses.mydomain.com
"txt-value-1"
"txt-value0-2"

As long as your clients are using their own credentials, emails flow just fine, once you confirm everything is good, you can remove your record from there.

If no,

You can still use SES sending authorization and allow them to use the domain verified in your account, doing this, they can only use your sending domain to send emails but emails will go from their account and they will be charged, their account should be in production.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization.html

Comment: Fantastic, didn't realize TXT records could have multiple entries.  Thank you so very much!